# How to get the number of elemets in an np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-2.6

Suppose there is an array

```
(1) x=np.array([[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]])
```

and a second array

```
(2) y=np.array([[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]])
```

The command `size(x)` returns the total count of all elements along every axis. In this case `6`. However, `size(y)` returns `3`. This must be because numpy interprets (2) in this case as three elements (the three subarrays) along one axis, although `shape(y)` returns `(3, )`. My question is now: how can I get numpy to interpret (2) as an array with three axes, so that `size(y)` returns the total count of all atomic elemets, which is `6`?

Comment: Note that `x` is a 2 by 3 `ndarray` of type 'int64', while `y` is a 3-element `ndarray` of type 'object', such that `x` and `y` are completely different. Numpy only supports matrices, not lists of lists (of arbitrary length).

Comment: You'll have to reshuffle the elements in `y`, or add padding. Arrays have to be square (matrix/tensor-like).

Comment: What are you trying to do in the second case? Maybe you could solve by simply adding 0s to pad these lists(like larsmans said).
numpy can manage only ndimensional arrays, so either you "normalize" y, or you have to avoid numpy if you really have to use lists of different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to get the number of elements from `y` without looping over the objects.

The problem is that the elements of `y` are not numbers, they are objects (lists). Numpy does not support lists of lists and therefore it stores it as a 1-dimensional array of objects. I don't think there are Numpy methods to get the total number of elements in `y`.